# PHP function to set the default value as an object

Tags: php, object, default-arguments

A function (actually the constructor of another class) needs an object of `class temp` as argument. So I define `interface itemp` and include `itemp $obj` as the function argument. This is fine, and I must pass `class temp` objects to my function. But now I want to set default value to this `itemp $obj` argument. How can I accomplish this?

Or is it not possible?

The test code to clarify:

```
interface itemp { public function get(); }

class temp implements itemp
{
    private $_var;
    public function __construct($var = NULL) { $this->_var = $var; }
    public function get() { return $this->_var ; }
}
$defaultTempObj = new temp('Default');

function func1(itemp $obj)
{
    print "Got: " . $obj->get() . " as argument.\n";
}

function func2(itemp $obj = $defaultTempObj) //error : unexpected T_VARIABLE
{
    print "Got: " . $obj->get() . " as argument.\n";
}

$tempObj = new temp('foo');

func1($defaultTempObj); // Got: Default as argument.
func1($tempObj); // Got : foo as argument.
func1(); // "error : argument 1 must implement interface itemp (should print Default)"
//func2(); // Could not test as I can't define it
```

Comment: You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, check my answer, please

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't. But you can easily do that:

```
function func2(itemp $obj = null)
    if ($obj === null) {
        $obj = new temp('Default');
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: thanks [found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224014/php-default-function-argument-as-a-t-variable/2224044#2224044) after searching for php method defaults, didn't think that I can compare object with nulls.

Answer (score 5):

### PHP 8.1

Since PHP 8.1 you are able to define a new instance of an object as a default value of the function argument without error, however with some limitations.

```
function someFunction(Item $obj = new Item('Default'))
{
    ...
}
```

Documentation: *[PHP RFC: New in initializers](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/new_in_initializers)*

Answer (score 4):

A possible problem with [Arnaud Le Blanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064970/php-function-to-set-the-default-value-as-an-object/7065015#7065015) is that in some cases you might wish to allow `NULL` as a specified parameter, e.g. you might wish for the following to be handled differently:

```
func2();
func2(NULL);
```

If so, a better solution would be:

```
function func2(itemp $obj = NULL)
{

  if (0 === func_num_args())
  {
    $obj = new temp('Default');
  }

  // ...

}
```

Comment: Does this make sense? The only valid parameter values are `null` and implementations of `itemp`. There is (or atleast should be from an API perspective) no behavorial difference in passing a marker for an absent value (`null`) and no value at all. I agree, if the parameter would not be typehinted, this is actually usefull in some cases.

Comment: If you're not passing a parameter then you're doing so intentionally, and so you might want it to perform some default behaviour. If you're passing a `NULL` parameter then it's likely expecting an `itemp` implementation and so you might want it to log an error and/or throw an exception.

Comment: sneaky, that way you're introducing a bit of overloading to php. I like it. Not sure if I'd endorse it, but who cares... :)

Answer (score 2):

Since [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) you can simply use the [`::class`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php) to pass a class as a parameter as follow:

```
function func2($class = SomeObject::class) {
    $object = new $class;
}

func2(); // Will create an instantiation of SomeObject class
func2(AnotherObject::class); // Will create an instantiation of the passed class
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly it doesn't work together with a type hint:
function func2(SomeInterface $class = SomeObject::class)
yields a Fatal: "Default value for parameters with a class type can only be NULL" (Tested with PHP 7.2)

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
function func2(itemp $obj = null)
    $obj = ValueResolver::resolve($obj, new temp('Default'));
    // ....
}
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples