# What is ::class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, laravel

What is the `::class` notation in PHP?

A quick Google search returns nothing because of the nature of the syntax.

colon colon class

What's the advantage of using this notation?

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
];
```

Answer (score 139):

`SomeClass::class` will return the fully qualified name of `SomeClass` including the namespace. This feature was implemented in PHP 5.5.

Documentation: [http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205192011/https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php)

It's very useful for 2 reasons.

- You don't have to store your class names in strings anymore. So, many IDEs can retrieve these class names when you refactor your code
- You can use the `use` keyword to resolve your class and you don't need to write the full class name.

For example :

```
use \App\Console\Commands\Inspire;

//...

protected $commands = [
    Inspire::class, // Equivalent to "App\Console\Commands\Inspire"
];
```

**Update** :

This feature is also useful for *[Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)*.

Instead of using the `__CLASS__` magic constant, you can use the `static::class` feature to get the name of the derived class inside the parent class. For example:

```
class A {

    public function getClassName(){
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public function getRealClassName() {
        return static::class;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

echo $a->getClassName();      // A
echo $a->getRealClassName();  // A
echo $b->getClassName();      // A
echo $b->getRealClassName();  // B
```

Comment: A slight correction: in the first example, `Inspire::class` is equivalent to "App\Console\Commands\Inspire", without the backward slash prefix.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi : note that the two notations `use \App\...` and `use App\...` are allowed. I use that to make the difference between a class contained in a subnamespace and a class contained outside the current namespace hierarchy.

Comment: A word of warning, you can type anything and still get a "class" name. I could type SomeDumbCrapThatDoesntExist::class and it won't give me an error or a warning if the IDE doesn't catch it. Easy to make a typo and miss it.

Answer (score 22):

The `::class` is a special keyword, which is provided by PHP to get the fully qualified class name.

See the [official PHP documentation about ::class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class).

```
<?php

class Foo {

    const EXAMPLE_CONSTANT = 'bar';

}

echo Foo::class;             // print Foo
echo Foo::EXAMPLE_CONSTANT;  // print bar
```

Comment: Is there a reason why Laravel decided to switch to it?

Comment: It is not a constant on the Inspire class. It is a constant provided by php. It is a quick way to get the fully qualified class name. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name

Comment: @Yada I believe the reasoning behind Laravel using it is that it gives you one less place to make a typo. You can use the string '\App\Console\Commands\Inspire' or Inspire::class to get the same thing, but your IDE will catch syntax/spelling errors on the latter making it a little easier to debug.

Comment: What does this code have to do with the question?

Comment: It would be nice to also mention some advantages, since, the OP requested them. But, I'm not the author of this question so it seems not correct to introduce them right now. Maybe we can introduce these as follow-up edit.

Answer (score 8):

If you're curious in which category it falls into (whether it's a language construct, etc),

It's just a **constant**.

PHP calls it a "Special Constant". It's special because it's provided by PHP at compile time.

> The special ::class constant is available as of PHP 5.5.0, and allows
> for fully qualified class name resolution at compile time, this is
> useful for namespaced classes:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware to use the following:

```
if ($whatever instanceof static::class) {...}
```

This will throw a syntax error:

> `unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`

But you can do the following instead:

```
if ($whatever instanceof static) {...}
```

or

```
$class = static::class;
if ($whatever instanceof $class) {...}
```

Comment: this hack for dynamic naming,  from php 5.* works like `$className = 'SomeCLass'; $className = new $className(); $methodName = 'someMethod'; $className->$methodName($arg1, $arg2, $arg3); /* or if args can be random array*/
call_user_func_array([$className, $methodName], $arg);`