# Seeding pivot table with Laravel 5.5 model factory - mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

Given that I have the following tables:

- users
- questions
- tags
- question_tag `my pivot table with two fields: question_id & tag_id`

and my **App\Question** model has the following relationships:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

I've created the following factories:

**database/factories/UserFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('123456')
    ];
});
```

**database/factories/QuestionFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\Question::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $user_id;

    return [
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'subject' => $faker->sentence(15),
        'body' => $faker->paragraph(10)
    ];
});
```

**database/factories/TagFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\Tag::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => str_slug($faker->words(mt_rand(1, 2))),
        'description' => $faker->sentence()
    ];
});
```

I tried to use it all together in my dummy data seeder like this:

```
class DummyDataSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Seed dummy users
        factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function($user)
        {
            // With dummy questions
            $user->questions()->saveMany(factory(App\Question::class, 10)->make()->each(function($question)
            {
                // With dummy tags
                $question->tags()->sync(factory(App\Tag::class, 3)->make());
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the seeder, I get the following error:

> [ErrorException]   mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given

Is this not possible to do in model factory? Do I need to use a different approach?

Comment: Run seed with `php artisan db:seed -vvv` to see more info about the error. Or check `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Thanks, the question is updated.

Comment: If you have a new question to ask, please do so rather than altering it after people have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use belongsToMany for your pivot Table

In Your Question model

```
public function tags()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class,'question_tag','tag_id','question_id');
 }
```

same with your Tag Model

```
public function questions()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class,'question_tag','question_id','tag_id');
}
```

also, You need to change

```
 $question->tags()->sync(factory(App\Tag::class, 3)->make());
```

to

```
$tags = factory(App\Tag::class, 3)->make();
$tagIds = Tag::select('id')->get()->toArray();
 $question->tags()->sync($tagIds);
```

which means you need to pass IDs in Sync argument.

Comment: I tried that and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share your User, Question and Tag Models?

Comment: also can you try to change from Make to create on dummy questions line

  $user->questions()->saveMany(factory(App\Question::class, 10)->create()->each(function($question)

Comment: Why? what's the difference?

Comment: @ankitpatel, either use `Question::class` without `'` (single quote) or `'App\Question'`. Take a look an [What is ::class in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php)

Comment: @Latheesan I update my answer, can you try with that?

Comment: @Ijubadr thank for your message, I put ' by mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked a separate question and managed to solve it in doing so also - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908594/2332336

Answer (score 0):

From [fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderlorem) readme:

`words($nb = 3, $asText = false) // array('porro', 'sed', 'magni')`.

will return array

Laravel [str_slug()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug)

> The str_slug function generates a URL friendly "slug" from the given string:
>   `$slug = str_slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');`

`str_slug` expects string

In your **database/factories/TagFactory.php** you need to fix the line:

```
'name' => str_slug($faker->words(mt_rand(1, 2))),
```

to

```
'name' => str_slug(implode(' ', $faker->words(mt_rand(1, 2)))),
```

or maybe

```
'name' => str_slug($faker->sentence(mt_rand(1, 2))),
```

Comment: Okay, the error was caused by the incorrect faker usage, not the migration. I have corrected it in my factory like this: `'name' => str_slug($faker->words(mt_rand(1, 2), true), '-'),` - now I am getting a different error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()`

Comment: @Latheesan - I answered the original question (before it was edited), but you should avoid changing the question after getting the answer. Best thing would be to create a new question.