# Seeding many-to-many relationship with model factory in laravel - column cannot be null error

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

Given that I have the following tables:

- users
- questions
- tags
- question_tag `my pivot table with two fields: question_id & tag_id`

and these are my model relationships:

**User**

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

**Question**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

**Tag**

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
}
```

I have setup the database model factory correctly for each models.

With my seeder, here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. Seed 10 dummy users
2. For each dummy user, seed 10 dummy questions
3. For each dummy question, associate it with up-to 5 random tags

To achieve the above three goals, I wrote the following database seeder:

```
// Seed dummy users
factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function($user)
{
    // With dummy questions
    $user->questions()->saveMany(factory(App\Question::class, 10)->make()->each(function($question)
    {
        // With dummy tags
        $question->tags()->sync(factory(App\Tag::class, 5)->make());
    }));
});
```

When this runs, I am getting the following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'question_id' cannot be null (SQL: i
>   nsert into `question_tag` (`question_id`, `tag_id`) values (, 1))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1048 Column 'question_id' cannot be null

How do you seed a pivot table, whilst creating records via the database model factory?

---

This question is [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46900408/2332336) to another question I asked - but now I am getting a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DummyDataSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Seed dummy tags
        factory(App\Tag::class, 10)->create();
        $tagIds = DB::table('tags')->pluck('id')->toArray();

        // Seed dummy users
        factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function($user) use($tagIds)
        {
            // With dummy questions
            $user->questions()->saveMany(factory(App\Question::class, 3)
            ->create(['user_id' => $user->id])->each(function($question) use($tagIds)
            {
                // With dummy tags
                $question->tags()->sync(array_random($tagIds, mt_rand(1, 5)));
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

*Maybe there's a better a way to do this; but this is working for me.*

Answer (score 0):

When you use saveMany method, 
you should set Eloquent model instance as parameter like this.

```
$user->questions()->saveMany(factory(App\Question::class, 10)->make())->each(function($question)
{
    // With dummy tags
    $question->tags()->sync(factory(App\Tag::class, 5)->make());
});
```