# Can someone explain how call_user_func_array(array(arg1, arg2), []) works?

Tags: php, call-user-func-array

I know this is a really vague question, but I just don't intuitively get it. I'm mostly a javascript/java guy, so you'll have to excuse me.

What happens inside of that first array call when doing something like:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->statementType), array($args))
```

that turns it into a callback function that is a member of the $this object?  I get that it works, I just don't fully get why and it's bugging me.

Comment: `$this->statementType` should be a method name which exists in the `$this` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP you can define a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as an `array` that is a combination of a calling context and a function name.

If you use `[$this, $string]` it will call the function whose name is stored in `$string` on the `$this` instance. (`[$this, 'functionName']` would also work, it does not need to be a variable)

If you use `[$className, $string]` it will result in a static call. 
Examples here could be `['\Namespace\MyClass', 'functionName']` or `[\NameSpace\MyClass::class, 'functionName']` or with variables. The `::class` syntax has a number of advantages, as was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php). Static calling can also be done by a single string (`"\Namespace\MyClass::functionName"` for example)

The second array is, as the function documents it, the list of parameters to pass to the function when calling it, but I assume that part was already clear.

Comment: Thank you!  I probably could have found that in the docs somewhere, but I write PHP about once every two months.  Can I assume that you can only add two members into this sort of  callable array?  And while I have your ear is $className in the static variety just another string?

Comment: You can click through to the callable manual page if you want for a lot of info, but yes, it's always a context and a method. As for the static calling, I added a couple examples.