# Why aliases use ::class at the end in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I am beginner Laravel developer and wanted to ask you about why aliases in Laravel use ::class at the end for eaxmple: 'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class, that is, I know ::class means it will return fully qualified name of a class in a string format. Well, does it mean that if I use DB::insert() then it will be equivalent to Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::insert(). So, the use of ::class means  I do not have to write fully qualified name of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\DB::insert` is equivalent to a call to `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::insert()`, but not because the `::class` syntax.

It would also work if the line in `aliases` was a string, these are all the same:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DBFacade;

    'DB' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB', // (string) Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
    'DB' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class, // (string) Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
    'DB' => DBFacade::class, // (string) Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
```

`::class` is just a convenience feature, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42064777/7362396) for 2 reasons it is helpful.

The real reason you can call the "aliased" name (without a namespace) is because Laravel adds a method to the [autoloader](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/748a57942f1f1690010a5d6075d145383e128bc3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php#L167) that will [load](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/748a57942f1f1690010a5d6075d145383e128bc3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php#L65-L82) the class if requested by its aliased name using either PHPs [`class_alias`](http://php.net/class-alias) or an auto-generated stub class, based on the `aliases` array from your config file.