# Laravel command artisan not working as cron

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

In my Laravel shared host i have this CRON command:
`/usr/local/bin/php /home3/ahmedsk/laravel_app/artisan schedule:run 1>> /home3/ahmedsk/laravel_app/log/schedule_cron 2>&1`

in the log file 
`/home3/ahmedsk/laravel_app/log/schedule_cron`

i get this error
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home3/ahmedsk/laravel_app/artisan on line 33`

---

note: my local artisan code running normally

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't checked the file and line number reported in the error message. In any case, I presume the PHP interpreter at `/usr/local/bin/php` is too old for your Laravel version.

Comment: this is the line have a issus `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);` in artisan file in laravel root

Comment: [Do you have PHP/5.5 or greater?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php)

Comment: let me check for that, but i think it's by default 7.1 on my host

Comment: You can type `/usr/local/bin/php -v` to find out.

Comment: ops it's `5.4.45`

Comment: but in `php_selector` i already chosen php ver are 7.1, Are a method can i do it to upgrate php -v

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea of what your hosting service is or how it works. If it's a *shared* host then you're probably not allowed to upgrade anything but perhaps they have several versions available. Ask them.

Comment: Ok i will do, thanks so much for this useful information

Comment: i found new path for php higher version in `/opt/php71/bin/php` it's return 7.1 :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález This question is not duplicate, and its unique, I had a similar problem too, You gave the correct answer in comment, please remove duplicate mark!