# What is the best way, in passing parameters in Laravel Eloquent: Relationship (methods), as well what is difference in it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Actually I don't have idea what is difference in both methods

Laravel Official documentation uses this below method for declaring relationship

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone'); // HERE (App\Phone) Parameter 
    }
}
```

and most of the tutorials and experts (even in Laracon's) uses this below method.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Phone::class); // HERE (Phone::class) Parameter 
    }
}
```

In short what is difference in both, And which is convenient.

```
return $this->hasOne(Phone::class); // Method one
/// VS 
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone'); // Method Two
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is ::class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php). Also, you should always prefer the `::class` approach, as it's cleaner, and works well with IDEs' refactoring capabilities.

Comment: Both are same, If you dump(Phone::class) you will see 'App\Phone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since PHP 5.5 the class keyword is used for class name resolution. This means it returns the fully qualified ClassName. This is extremely useful when you have namespaces, because the namespace is part of the returned name.

Using the ::class keyword is the way to go. First because you write less, and second, using this your IDE can help you find the class faster.

But they're basically the same thing.

You can find more about that [here](https://christoph-rumpel.com/2016/03/using-the-class-keyword-in-PHP-and-Laravel)

Answer (score 1):

They are both the same but `Phone::class` is new syntax
let's assume you want to move your `Phone` class to another folder you have to find every `'App\Phone'` and rename it to `New\Directory\Phone` but when you use `Phone::class` you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: It is also shorter and more readable if the class has a long namespace.