# Why ::class is used when using a controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Why `::class` is written in Laravel 8 web.php

```
Route::get('/', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42064777/7451109

Answer (score 3):

Class is just a constant provided by PHP. You can do either

`Route::get('/', [UserController::class, 'show']);`

or

`Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show');`

When you use the `class` you can import it on top of your file by using `use` and  you don't have to store it in strings like the second example.