# Is new ClassName the same as ClassName::class - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I saw these two lines in the Kernal.php

```
$schedule->job(new SendJoinerReminderEmails)->dailyAt('09:00');
$schedule->job(SendLeaverReminderEmails::class)->dailyAt('09:00');
```

Functionally are these the same, and is one more correct than the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is ::class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php)

Comment: It helped but I didn't realise the actual job method was being clever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new SendJoinerReminderEmails` return class instance

`SendLeaverReminderEmails::class` path of class return `string` like `App\Mails\SendLeaverReminderEmails`

if you see `job` method

```
public function job($job, $queue = null, $connection = null)
{
        return $this->call(function () use ($job, $queue, $connection) {
            $job = is_string($job) ? Container::getInstance()->make($job) : $job;

            if ($job instanceof ShouldQueue) {
                $this->dispatchToQueue($job, $queue ?? $job->queue, $connection ?? $job->connection);
            } else {
                $this->dispatchNow($job);
            }
        })->name(is_string($job) ? $job : get_class($job));
    }
```

here if  `$job param` is `string` then it will try get instance from the `container`  or else it will take instance from the `$job param`

```
 $job = is_string($job) ? Container::getInstance()->make($job) : $job;
```

To check you can  dd

`dd(new SendJoinerReminderEmails)`

or

`dd(SendLeaverReminderEmails::class)`

Comment: So essentially there is a fundamental difference but in this case the framework doesn't care because it's flexible?

Comment: @JesseOrange at the end job method use instance of class .you can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php this link

Answer (score 2):

No, **Class instance** is not same as **Class name**.

- `new SomeClass()` will return an instance or object on the class.
- On the other hand `SomeClass::class` will return the fully qualified
  name of SomeClass

But in this case, both should work because the method `job()` accepts any of the `class name` or an `instance`.

If you pass the class name, it'll resolve the instance inside the method as follows-

```
$job = is_string($job) ? resolve($job) : $job;
```

See the full implementation of the `job` method below-

```
/**
 * Add a new job callback event to the schedule.
 *
 * @param  object|string  $job
 * @param  string|null  $queue
 * @param  string|null  $connection
 * @return \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent
 */
public function job($job, $queue = null, $connection = null)
{
    return $this->call(function () use ($job, $queue, $connection) {
        $job = is_string($job) ? resolve($job) : $job;

        if ($job instanceof ShouldQueue) {
            dispatch($job)
                ->onConnection($connection ?? $job->connection)
                ->onQueue($queue ?? $job->queue);
        } else {
            dispatch_now($job);
        }
    })->name(is_string($job) ? $job : get_class($job));
}
```