# Google cloud storage PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

Hi I am getting a strange error when I run the following script. It is returning this error message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /home/apipetfindr/public_html/sys/v1/google_cloud_storeage_upload.php on line 9
```

I am wondering why this part of my code is not working:

```
private $storage = new StorageClient
```

I know I need to call the new function I have tried public instead of private with no success. if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
<?php
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;


class googleupload{

  private $storage = new StorageClient([
      'projectId' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
  ]);

  private $bucket = $storage->bucket('BUCKET_NAME');

  // Upload a file to the bucket.
  //$bucket->upload(
  //    fopen('/data/file.txt', 'r')
  //);


  public function uploads($_FILE, $uid){
        $obj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
        $obj->setName($file_name);

        $resp = $storage->objects->insert(
            "bucketname",
            $obj,
            array('name' => $file_name, 'data' => file_get_contents("300mb-file.zip"), 'uploadType' => 'media')
        );

  }
}
/*
// Download and store an object from the bucket locally.
$object = $bucket->object('file_backup.txt');
$object->downloadToFile('/data/file_backup.txt');
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use something like `new Object(x, y, [z])` as a default value for a class property. If you want to have always the same property-value, e.g. your object with projectId xxxx, you can put something like this within your constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->storage = new StorageClient(['projectId' => 'xxxxxxxx']);
  $this->bucket = $this->storage->bucket('BUCKET_NAME');
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, do you have any reference for this? Because coming from C#, his code would be perfectly fine.

Comment: If i put this into my IDE (Intellij if someone wants to know) it tells me "expression is not allowed as field default value". Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224044/7008354) SO question.

Comment: Ah yes, but that's talking about the default value of a function argument. Of course that can't be any dynamic value. In this case he's instantiating a new object that may or may not require some argument(s) depening on whether the object can be overloaded or not. It seems to me that's something different than what you're talking about. Unless `private $storage` is treated like a function somehow.. Could be wrong here, just trying to learn :)

Comment: Ah, never mind. I think I found what you were talking about in the docs for [Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`

Comment: You found the right words, thats what i was thinking about :)

Comment: Yup. Well done in noticing the issue though! As I said: In most OOP languages his code would be perfectly fine. Although even there it's rarely used like that. Still I wouldn't have noticed it myself.

Comment: I also had this issue once, so there was this "wait a second, i have seen this before" effect.

Comment: I am getting an error when using that code 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/apipetfindr/public_html/sys/v1/google_cloud_storeage_upload.php on line 10

Comment: Have you put the code in the constructor? It should look like in my answer now.